# In Theorem 10.1 of Topology by Munkres, what is really going on? I need some help to understand it properly...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory

(1) While proving Theorem 10.1, Munkres talks about non-empty, finite, ordered sets - Does he mean simply ordered set? If so, don't simply ordered set already have an order relation on them which can automatically be used to show them being well-ordered?

(2) Why does he talk about largest elements in the set? Why not smallest?

Its very confusing...

Comment: [Munkres has written several books](https://zbmath.org/?au=Munkres&dt=b), some having more than one edition. You need to be more specific than "Theorem 10.1, Munkres".

Comment: Thanks, I added the book.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the statement and proof of the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he is talking about linearly (or simply) ordered sets. In order to show that the linear order is actually a well-order, you’d have to show that every non-empty subset of the set had a least element with respect to the linear order. That can be done in much the same way that Munkres shows that every finite linearly ordered set has a greatest element, but he wants to prove more than just that the set is well-ordered: he wants to prove specifically that it has the order type of a section of $\Bbb Z_+$.

That proof *could* be done by showing that every finite linearly ordered set has a least element, but the induction step would be just a little messier; he’s chosen the simpler approach. The other version would go as follows, where I follow his language as closely as possible.

> Second, we show there is an order-preserving bijection of $A$ with $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some $n$. If $A$ has one element, this fact is trivial. Suppose that it is true for sets having $n-1$ elements. Let $b$ be the smallest element of $A$. By hypothesis, there is an order-preserving bijection
>
> $$f':A\setminus\{b\}\to\{1,\ldots,n-1\}\,.$$
>
> Define an order-preserving bijection $f:A\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by setting
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> f(x)&=f'(x)+1,\text{if }x\ne b\\
> f(b)&=1\,.
> \end{align*}$$

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. Then here is a follow up question: he first says, lets suppose it is true for n-1, then show it true for n. Is he using a baby-version of "principle of recursive definition" (theorem 8.4)? "Baby-version" because  theorem 8.4 works for Z+ and here we only want it for Sn.

Comment: @DonaldObama: No, he’s doing a straightforward proof by induction on $n$. If you’re thinking of the definition of $f$, that is not recursive: $f$ is defined all at once in terms of $f'$.

Comment: Pardon me but when one says "proof by induction" don't they really mean by recursive definition(a point made after Lemma 7.2)? 
PS - I am new at math, hence trying to make sure I really understand what I think I understand.

Comment: @DonaldObama: Absolutely not; they aren’t even the same **kind** of thing. Mathematical induction is a specific technique for proving theorems; recursive definition is a specific method of defining mathematical objects. It happens that theorems about recursively defined objects are often most easily proved by induction, because there are underlying structural similarities between recursive definition and proof by induction, but the two are fundamentally distinct. In that passage following Lemma $7.2$ Munkres is actually misusing the term *induction* when he says that he’s used it to ...

Comment: ... construct something: he’s actually used recursion. Unfortunately, this misuse is rather common. In a serious course in set theory one would prove from the axioms of set theory that recursive definitions are legitimate; this does not follow from the principle of induction that Munkres is using, so he’s waving his hands a bit. This is understandable: he can’t really do anything else unless he wants to make a good introduction to set theory a prerequisite.

Comment: Aah, I see. Thank you so much for clarifying it. Can you, please, point me to a book which talks about the proof behind mathematical induction, then? I mean the reason why must it work? I would love to know how induction works (behind the scenes).

Comment: @DonaldObama: Induction over the positive integers — if $1\in S$ and $n+1\in S$ whenever $n\in S$, then $S=\Bbb Z^+$ — is one of the Peano axioms for the positive integers; short of going through a development of axiomatic set theory, it’s probably best simply to take it as an axiom. One *does* need to do some axiomatic set theory to see a proof justifying recursive definitions; Hrbacek & Jech, *Introduction to Set Theory* is good, though almost certainly overkill. If you’d just like to see exactly what the recursion theorem says, ...

Comment: ... [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) has a clear statement and partial proof, though the actual proof of existence of the defined function is beyond the scope of such an article.